# django can't save model choices selected values

Tags: django

I want to save selected choice in model charfield
My models.py:

```
qobj = Model1.objects.all()

CHOICE = (
    (x.id, x.name) for x in qobj
)


class Model2(models.Model):
    choice_field = models.CharField(max_length=77, choices=CHOICE)

class Model2Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ['choice_field']
```

When I try to save model2 I got error:

> "Select a valid choice. 5 is not one of the available choices.".

I was trying `forms.ModelChoiceField` but I can't get `Model2.get_choice_field_display()`, `forms.ChoiceField` and widget `Select` to work.
May be someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question including your form code and the views code of how you are using the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you were defining `choice_field` as `CharField`, but your choices are using `id` as keys, which are integers. You need to change the `choice_field` to be `models.IntegerField`.

Also, sounds like your `choice_field` is based on another model's entries. Your way of populating data might not work because your `CHOICES` variable would get evaluated only once. You should use `ForeignKey` for `choice_field` instead:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    choice_field = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
```

If you use django default way of rendering form, `ForeignKey` would be rendered as a dropdown just like `choices`, so you should definitely use that.

Comment: I was not try  IntegerField. May be You right. And choice values is not integers?

Comment: but Model1 is not choicefields contain

Comment: qobj - is a sum of several models objects values. When i do choices=CHOICE, CHOICE is a  qobj. Question is - right i do CHOICE? Other methods will not work without change of all.

Comment: Yes, I solving this with ManyToMany. But I don`t like this drop box i want  Select widget.